Azure storage account key in project metadata triggering git push protection
I have been in a struggle recently with all the projects i create on visual studio on my laptop.
Every time i try to push my code to GitHub i get the exact same push protection notification about my azure storage key in my project metadata.
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: error: GH013: Repository rule violations found for refs/heads/main.
remote:
remote: - GITHUB PUSH PROTECTION
remote:   —————————————————————————————————————————
remote:     Resolve the following violations before pushing again
remote:
remote:     - Push cannot contain secrets
remote:
remote:
remote:      (?) Learn how to resolve a blocked push
remote:      https://docs.github.com/code-security/secret-scanning/pushing-a-branch-blocked-by-push-protection
remote:
remote:
remote:       —— Azure Storage Account Access Key ——————————————————
remote:        locations:
remote:          - commit: ff71ce2fa3921849c2ab6d35e3163c15a473ad15
remote:            path: .vs/ProjectEvaluation/digitallibrary.metadata.v7.bin:2
remote:
remote:        (?) To push, remove secret from commit(s) or follow this URL to allow the secret.
remote:        https://github.com/pineapple-pizza25/digital-library---linked-lists/security/secret-scanning/unblock-secret/2k4AbpwXUTcrMhkE5FL6o7Vrpn3
remote:
remote:
remote:

Please advise on what i can do to fix this.

This error means that your GitHub repository has enabled secret scanning. Since the storage account key is actually a secret, GitHub prevents your commit from being pushed to remote. The whole purpose of this is to prevent leaks of vulnerable data.
You can follow this link to get instruction how to disable secret scanning for your repo.
